# Invalid directory path when opening a file

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle SQL Developer, I started to write a script which will take the result of a query, format data and write modified data to txt file (position field file)

```
declare
  ...
  out_file UTL_FILE.FILE_THYPE;
begin
  out_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('C\USER\BOB', 'TEST.TXT' 'W');

  ...
end
```

I always get

> invalid directory path, a corresponding directory object does not
> exist

tried

```
 out_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('C:\TEMP', 'TEST.TXT' 'W');
```

but get same result, file and folder exist

Answer (score 3):

you need to create the directory and use it as follows:

```
Create or replace directory dir_name
As 'C\USER\BOB';
```

Then use it in your code:

```
UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR_NQME', 'TEST.TXT' 'W');
```

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation, *[PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70919)*, Table 251-9 FOPEN Function Parameters:

> location
>
> Directory location of file. This string is a directory object name and
> must be specified in upper case. Read privileges must be granted on
> this directory object for the UTL_FILE user to run FOPEN.

Notice that the location is "a directory object name". Not the actual directory name.  You need to create a directory object.

```
CREATE DIRECTORY admin AS '/disk1/oracle/admin';
```

(See *[SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5008.htm#SQLRF01207)*,